# Office365 Notification API not updated, property 'ChangeType' does not exist

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Everyone,

According this link, [Microsoft Office365 Notification API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations#NotificationoperationsSubscribetochangesinmycalendar_mailbox_andcontacts), in order to create a simple webhook, i should do:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
   @odata.type:"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
   ResourceURL: "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/events",
   CallbackURL: "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",  
   ChangeType: "Created",
   ClientState: "c75831bd-fad3-4191-9a66-280a48528679"
}
```

and adding the access token in headers of course as well, 
i did try and each time i get the following result:

```
{u'error': {u'message': u"The property 'ChangeType' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.", u'code': u'RequestBodyRead'}}
```

So basically, since i simply copy their examples, should i have to assume that their API documentation is outdated?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the beta endpoint was updated. You're likely in the transitional phase where it was renamed to `changeType`. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/10/21/outlook-rest-api-changes-to-beta-endpoint-part-iii.aspx for full details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, indeed it works great now, not easy to program with bleeding edge apis :)

Comment: I hear ya! Be sure to check our blog often if you're using the beta endpoint, we try to give advance notice there of breaking changes.

Comment: Jason, Let me ask you a question please, why keep developing this API while there is a new API coming, this so called Office 365 Management Activity API, which on top of that will be integrated with unified api in futur, this last one seems to bring much more events .., is there something i missuderstood?

Comment: The unified API uses the Outlook API, so development on the Outlook API makes its way to the unified API, though it does usually take a bit longer.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jason, very much apreciated !!